# Php echo the link

Tags: php, html

I have that code:

```
echo('<br/>');
echo "<img src='".print_r((string)($product->Imagine))."' />".('<br/>');
```

I am expecting to see an image on my browser. But the output source of the above code is:

```
<br/>/AdminImages/Products/tsJanta_1/40890_big.jpg<img src='1' /><br/>
```

Could somebody tell me why it doesn't work the code as I did it?

Comment: remove the `print_r`

Comment: echo "<img src='".(string)($product->Imagine)."' /><br/>";

Comment: hi, doesn't my answer fix your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

print_r is a special function mainly used for debugging. It doesn't return text the same way at all unless you set it's second parameter to true.

You should simply use `echo "<img src='".$product->Imagine."' />".('<br/>');`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php